# Display child pages in a parent page?

Tags: pages, child-pages

I have a "News" page with child pages and I want to display those child pages in "News" page only, like [this](http://dgmanila.com)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this: [`get_page_children()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children)

That function will return an array of your sub-pages, which you can iterate through to display your list.

Comment: can you give me another snippet?

Comment: I don't work for free - there's enough snippets on the reference page for you to get going with some experiments.

Comment: @user3818821 it is expected that you have at least the minimum knowledge to implement what have been given in an answer. The given link should help you reach your goal

Comment: @PieterGoosen and BejaminLove please see updated question

Comment: @user3818821 As far as I can see, the issue is resolved ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen yes, but I want to displayed the child pages with limited content on each (55 characters only) and put some button

Comment: @user3818821 that should be a **new** question. I'm going to roll back your edit. Please do not edit existing posts in order to ask a new question

Comment: Ok sorry, I add the new question now